# Why we cannot assign an object directly to method which returns the same type?

Tags: c#, object, methods, reference

I'm asking this out of curiosity and I'm aware about other ways of doing so.

I was wondering, if some method is returning an object of some type and we can modify that object's property directly (on the fly - without taking it's reference into local variable).

Why do we need to take it's reference into local variable to change the object itself?

What logical difficulties can be there at compiler level which restrict programmer to do so.

See example code below:

```
static Demo StaticDemoInstance;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //allowed: means I can directly modify property of static instance
    //  received from method
    GetDemo().Name = "UpdateDemo";

    //allowed: means I can get instance and overwrite it with other instance
    //      but not directly from method
    Demo d = GetDemo();
    d = new Demo("NewCreatedDemo", false);

    //not allowed: means I can't do second step directly on method
    //  question: 
    //      when I can update instance property without receiving instance on local variable
    //      what possible violation/difficulty (in compiler) will be there so it doesn't allow this
    GetDemo() = new Demo("UpdatedDemoFromGetMeth", false);
}

static Demo GetDemo() => StaticDemoInstance ?? 
                         StaticDemoInstance = new Demo("StaticDemo", false);
```

Comment: `GetDemo() = new Demo("UpdatedDemoFromGetMeth", false);` you are... not assigning properties.. `GetDemo()` is a method.. beware downvoters.

Comment: @BagusTesa yes I know.. i have written that in question itselft `GetDemo().Name = "UpdateDemo";` I'm setting properties

Comment: well, you can see @TheGeneral's answer below, but its on C#7.0 only. i still stuck on 5.

Comment: Why would you want to do this, rather than just making `GetDemo()` a writable `Demo` property?

Comment: @BagusTesa Then you can't... Simply as that :-) Note that even with `ref` you can `ref` only a local variable or a field, not a property. So its uses are a little limited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could always use a [Ref return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns#what-is-a-reference-return-value)

> Starting with C# 7.0, C# supports reference return values (ref
>   returns). A reference return value allows a method to return a
>   reference to a variable, rather than a value, back to a caller. The
>   caller can then choose to treat the returned variable as if it were
>   returned by value or by reference. The caller can create a new
>   variable that is itself a reference to the returned value, called a
>   ref local.

**Limitations**

> There are some restrictions on the expression that a method can return
>   as a reference return value. Restrictions include:
>
> - The return value must have a lifetime that extends beyond the execution of the method. In other words, it cannot be a local variable
>     in the method that returns it. It can be an instance or static field
>     of a class, or it can be an argument passed to the method. Attempting
>     to return a local variable generates compiler error CS8168, "Cannot
>     return local 'obj' by reference because it is not a ref local."
> - The return value cannot be the literal null. Returning null generates compiler error CS8156, "An expression cannot be used in this
>     context because it may not be returned by reference."
> - A method with a ref return can return an alias to a variable whose value is currently the null (uninstantiated) value or a nullable type
>     for a value type.
> - The return value cannot be a constant, an enumeration member, the by-value return value from a property, or a method of a class or
>     struct. Violating this rule generates compiler error CS8156, "An
>     expression cannot be used in this context because it may not be
>     returned by reference."

A really contrived example **and not what i recommend**, however it does achieve your goals (academically)

**Example**

```
static Demo StaticDemoInstance;

...

static ref Demo GetDemo()
{
   if (StaticDemoInstance == null)
      StaticDemoInstance = new Demo("StaticDemo", false);

   return ref StaticDemoInstance;
}

..

GetDemo() = new Demo("UpdatedDemoFromGetMeth", false);
```

**Update**

The use of it can be seen with further convoluted example and modifications

**Exmaple**

```
static Demo Test()
{
   return StaticDemoInstance;
}

...

GetDemo() = new Demo("UpdatedDemoFromGetMeth", false);
var someObject = Test();
someObject= new Demo("Test", false);

Console.WriteLine(StaticDemoInstance.Name);
Console.WriteLine(someObject.Name);
```

**Output**

```
UpdatedDemoFromGetMeth
Test
```

The `Test` method (is not ref return) and only giving you a copy of the reference (for lack of better terminology), if you overwrite it, your static variable to `StaticDemoInstance` doesn't change

Comment: yeah i have read your earlier answer on the same, and that only triggered my curiosity! if c# 7 has introduced that, it must be useful to do so!! but question "why we needed to write `ref` explicitly and can't do directly" was killing me.

Comment: After seeing your update i went to up-vote button.. found that i have already done that for first of your post.. now i need double up-vote :D